# ValueError: 'images' must have either 3 or 4 dimensions

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I have a trouble with my program for detection and i've tried diffrent solution i could get only from restarting,trying to plug and unplug my camera, etc. and all of the solution doesn't seems to work, so i've been thinking there's something wrong on my code and yet i dont really know what. the error on the code seems to be saying that it could no detect the 3 and 4 dimension.

This is the main code

```
while True: 
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    image_np = np.array(frame)
    
    input_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(np.expand_dims(image_np, 0), dtype=tf.float32)
    detections = detect_fn(input_tensor)
    
    num_detections = int(detections.pop('num_detections'))
    detections = {key: value[0, :num_detections].numpy()
                  for key, value in detections.items()}
    detections['num_detections'] = num_detections

    # detection_classes should be ints.
    detections['detection_classes'] = detections['detection_classes'].astype(np.int64)

    label_id_offset = 1
    image_np_with_detections = image_np.copy()

    viz_utils.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
                image_np_with_detections,
                detections['detection_boxes'],
                detections['detection_classes']+label_id_offset,
                detections['detection_scores'],
                category_index,
                use_normalized_coordinates=True,
                max_boxes_to_draw=5,
                min_score_thresh=.5,
                agnostic_mode=False)

    cv2.imshow('object detection',  cv2.resize(image_np_with_detections, (800, 600)))
    
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        cap.release()
        break
```

---

This is the error code

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
4
5     input_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(np.expand_dims(image_np, 0), dtype=tf.float32)
----> 6     detections = detect_fn(input_tensor)
7
8     num_detections = int(detections.pop('num_detections'))

```
F:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwds)
    887 
    888       with OptionalXlaContext(self._jit_compile):
--> 889         result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
    890 
    891       new_tracing_count = self.experimental_get_tracing_count()

F:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py in _call(self, *args, **kwds)
    922       # In this case we have not created variables on the first call. So we can
    923       # run the first trace but we should fail if variables are created.
--> 924       results = self._stateful_fn(*args, **kwds)
    925       if self._created_variables:
    926         raise ValueError("Creating variables on a non-first call to a function"

F:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
   3020     with self._lock:
   3021       (graph_function,
-> 3022        filtered_flat_args) = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
   3023     return graph_function._call_flat(
   3024         filtered_flat_args, captured_inputs=graph_function.captured_inputs)  # pylint: disable=protected-access

F:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py in _maybe_define_function(self, args, kwargs)
   3442 
   3443           self._function_cache.missed.add(call_context_key)
-> 3444           graph_function = self._create_graph_function(args, kwargs)
   3445           self._function_cache.primary[cache_key] = graph_function
   3446 

F:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py in _create_graph_function(self, args, kwargs, override_flat_arg_shapes)
   3287             arg_names=arg_names,
   3288             override_flat_arg_shapes=override_flat_arg_shapes,
-> 3289             capture_by_value=self._capture_by_value),
   3290         self._function_attributes,
   3291         function_spec=self.function_spec,

F:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\func_graph.py in func_graph_from_py_func(name, python_func, args, kwargs, signature, func_graph, autograph, autograph_options, add_control_dependencies, arg_names, op_return_value, collections, capture_by_value, override_flat_arg_shapes)
    997         _, original_func = tf_decorator.unwrap(python_func)
    998 
--> 999       func_outputs = python_func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
   1000 
   1001       # invariant: `func_outputs` contains only Tensors, CompositeTensors,

F:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py in wrapped_fn(*args, **kwds)
    670         # the function a weak reference to itself to avoid a reference cycle.
    671         with OptionalXlaContext(compile_with_xla):
--> 672           out = weak_wrapped_fn().__wrapped__(*args, **kwds)
    673         return out
    674 

F:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\func_graph.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    984           except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
    985             if hasattr(e, "ag_error_metadata"):
--> 986               raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
    987             else:
    988               raise

ValueError: in user code:

    <ipython-input-18-f5bf27ce595e>:11 detect_fn  *
        image, shapes = detection_model.preprocess(image)
    F:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\object_detection\meta_architectures\ssd_meta_arch.py:484 preprocess  *
        normalized_inputs, self._image_resizer_fn)
    F:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\object_detection\utils\shape_utils.py:492 resize_images_and_return_shapes  *
        outputs = static_or_dynamic_map_fn(
    F:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\object_detection\utils\shape_utils.py:246 static_or_dynamic_map_fn  *
        outputs = [fn(arg) for arg in tf.unstack(elems)]
    F:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\object_detection\core\preprocessor.py:3327 resize_image  *
        new_image = tf.image.resize_images(
    F:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\dispatch.py:206 wrapper  **
        return target(*args, **kwargs)
    F:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\image_ops_impl.py:1544 resize_images
        skip_resize_if_same=True)
    F:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\image_ops_impl.py:1396 _resize_images_common
        raise ValueError('\'images\' must have either 3 or 4 dimensions.')

    ValueError: 'images' must have either 3 or 4 dimensions.
```

Comment: Check the output of `ret, frame = cap.read()` is image, if not may be its lag between webcam and the code accessing it. Use some sleep time , `time.sleep(.5)   # simulate time between events` . Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

u just got error from ur webcam, as specifically u got lag between ur webcam and ur system, and the solution is u need to change ur code `cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):` to `key == ord('q'):` and before if u should add `key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF` and at the end of ur line add this `cap.release()` and this `cv2.destroyAllWindows()`